# Shell Scripting: calculate power of a number with a real number as an exponent

Tags: shell-script, bc

I am using shell scripting and I am using the following expression:

```
A=`echo "(( (($a / $b) ^ 0.3) -1 ))" |bc -l`
```

I want to have a real number as an exponent. I noticed that If I place 0.3, it rounds off to an integer and takes the power of zero. Similarly if I use 5.5 or 5.9 in place of 0.3 in the above expression, I get the same answer.

How do I calculate the power of a number with the exponent being a real number and not an integer

Comment: Do you get a `non-zero scale in exponent` error? if so, it's a limitation of `bc` I think: see for example [Using fractional exponent with bc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164925/using-fractional-exponent-with-bc)

Comment: It just uses the integer value and not the real number. with 5.5 it will take the exponent of 5. Similarly with 0.3 it will take the exponent of 0

Comment: You could try ``A=`echo "( e(0.3 * l($a / $b)) -1 )" | bc -l` ``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why can't you use awk or perl one-liner to handle it?

```
echo "$a $b" | awk '{ print ((($1/$2)^0.3) -1); }'
```

Answer (score 10):

You cannot directly use the `^` operator to raise to a non-integer exponent, however, you can use the identity

a<sup>b</sup> = e<sup>ln(a) × b</sup>

with `e` being the base of the natural logarithm. `bc`, when called with the `-l` option, has the functions `e` and `l` to compute base-`e` exponentiation and the natural logarithm respectively, so in order to compute `a^b` you just write `e(l(a)*b)`.

For example, for 2<sup>0.5</sup> (square root of 2):

```
$ echo 'e(l(2)*0.5)' | bc -l
1.41421356237309504878
```

Comment: For this example with ^0.5 there is bc `sqrt()` function.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you can't use `bc` for that. It doesn't support floating point exponents. As explained in `man bc`:

> expr ^ expr
>
> The result of the expression is the value of the first raised to
>         the second. **The second expression must be an integer**.  [ ... ]

So, you'll have to use something else such as `awk`:

```
awk -va="$a" -vb="$b" 'BEGIN{print ((a/b)^0.3)-1}'
```

or, as suggested by Dennis Jacob:

```
echo "$a $b" | awk '{print ((($1/$2)^0.3) -1);}'
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -le 'print ((($ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1])**0.3)-1)' "$a" "$b"
```

or

```
echo "$a $b" | perl -lane 'print ((($F[0]/$F[1])**0.3) -1)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use r instead of bc:

```
A=$(echo "x=( ( ($a / $b) ** .3 ) -1 );print (x)" | r)
```

but of course more programming languages can solve this.